# let utransmission run even after lid closed?

Tags: wireless, laptop, power-management, suspend, downloads

How do I set my settings such that even if I close my lid (Laptop) 
My downloads don't stop or pause in utransmission
I have set the setting in power options to not suspend after closing lid still doesn't have Time out is off as well in power option 
but this doesn't help 
also wifi goes off when I close the lid .

I just want my torrents running even if I close the lid or keep the laptop untouched for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Sleep state may be set by the BIOS. It is advised to check there for power management settings.

When you reboot your PC, try hitting F10. One of these keys will enter BIOS settings. Then, try to navigate to the power management tab. Make sure all settings are disabled.

You also need to go into the power management control panel and disable screen timeout and all button actions.

If this doesn't work, your BIOS is simply not allowing this to happen. It also might be the kernel or your ACPI power management module.

Comment: thank you mister
but I dint find any kind of power management settings in my bios system configration 
i need to press f10 for getting into bios menu
I have to let my lid open while downloading

Comment: @SchezanMansuri If this helped, hit the checkmark button by the voting arrows. Thanks!

Comment: Dint really help but 

I am glad that you tried to help me :)

Comment: If I didn't help, uncheck this post. Sorry, I thought this solved your problem.

Comment: I guess its hardware issue 
as we close the lid the wifi switches off automatically

Answer (score 0):

Configure your power settings something like this:

open terminal and type `unity-control-center power` to open "Power" settings

Or go to `System Settings` and find there `Power`

[image]

Comment: dint help :( already with the same settings 
but thanks :D

Comment: @SchezanMansuri Have you tried adding the kernel options "acpi=off apm=off" to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` like this  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ="acpi=off apm=off"` in `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`?

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot your computer.

Comment: I dont know what are kernels and how to handle them
AND ALSO scared if i will mess up something

Comment: @SchezanMansuri just run `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and then find this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT ="quiet splash acpi=off apm=off"` and press <Ctrl>+<S> to save this file then close gedit and run `sudo update-grub` and then restart. now check if it fixed, so your problem solved AND if not solved open again file `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` and change that line to default value and save file and run `sudo update-grub` and restart.

Comment: thanks finally i know what kernel is 
but download still pauses as the wifi switches off

Comment: @SchezanMansuri Is your system goes to suspend when you close the lid? or not it still power on?

Comment: I guess power stays on because applications dont close but wifi goes off

Comment: Ok then don't change this file `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. did you change it?

Comment: Yes i got back to orignal

Comment: I have looked in the internet and I found more similar problem same as your's which didn't solve and I think this is a bug, but no one reported it as a bug. you can report that as a first user [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug). sorry